# To show Range of a function is finite

Tags: functions

Let f(x) = $\frac{1-\frac{x}{b}}{\frac{1}{b}-x}$ and 0 < x < 1 and 0 < b < 1

I know the denominator will never get to be zero. One of the solution says that's why range of f(x) cannot be R (real number) or infinite and therefore it is finite. I understand on solving other way it is -1 < f(x) < b

I couldn't understand how just because the denominator cannot be zero, f(x) range can be finite, because the denominator can still approach zero.

Thanks

Comment: You may be being confused by the notation. $0 < x < 1$ is presumably meant to be a variable that can take on all of the values in the range.  $0 < b < 1$ is presumably meant to be a constant that takes on one value in the range.  Clearly $\frac{1}{b}>1$ and so the denominator takes on a range which does not include 0. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Isn't both x and b are variables because they both can take any number between 0 and 1.

Comment: Well it's your question so $b$ can be whatever you like. If it's a variable then $1/b$ can be as close to 1 (from above) as you like and $x$ can be as close to 1 (from below) as you like so $\frac{1}{b}-x$ can be as close to zero as you like and so $f$ is unbounded. If, on the other hand, $b$ is a constant, then $f$ is bounded.

Comment: But the fact you write $f(x)$ rather than $f(x,b)$ suggests that $b$ is not a  variable.

Answer (score 0):

First note that since $0 < b < 1$, then $1 < \frac{1}{b} < \infty$. The denominator of $f(x)$ only approaches zero in the domain $0 < x < 1$ if $x \rightarrow 1$ and $b \rightarrow 1$, but in that case the numerator $1 - \frac{x}{b} \rightarrow 1 - \frac{1}{1} = 0$. To check that this is okay, let $b=x$ and calculate the limit
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{1 - \frac{x}{x}}{\frac{1}{x} - x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{0}{\frac{1}{x} - x} = 0.$$

Comment: From the above I understand whenever x=b, f(x) =0. But how does this prove range of f(x) is finite?

Comment: Well, under what conditions does a rational function (like f(x)) go to infinite? If the denominator approaches zero at a point where the numerator is nonzero, the function is infinite. If the numerator approaches infinity at a point where the denominator is finite, the function is infinite. We can check that neither of these things happens in your example f(x); if so, then the range of the function is finite.

Comment: In the second case, the numerator approaches infinity when $x\to 1$ and $b\to 0$ i.e $\frac{x}{b} \to \infty $ so the numerator $(1-\frac{x}{b}) \to - \infty  $. And in the denominator $\frac{1}{b} \to \infty$ , i.e denominator$(\frac{1}{b}-x) \to + \infty$.

Doesn't this makes f(x) indeterminate. So how does this make f(x) not infinite in the second case.

Comment: Ah I missed that case before. It's still not indeterminate though, since the numerator and denominator approach infinity at the same rate and cancel each other out (factor the negative sign out to the front).

Comment: If you're still confused, try rewriting $f(x)$ by multiplying both sides of the fraction by $b$ (this is a valid operation). Then you get $f(x) = \frac{b-x}{1-bx}$, which I think shows more clearly that it's okay when $b \rightarrow 0$.